# HP Storageworks MSA60, one failed disk replaced, all 12 bays flashing rapidly

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid6

I replaced a faulty disk yesterday afternoon, and the rebuild process started (RAID6). All disks were previously 750GB, but the only disk I could get is 1TB. Right now, almost 18 hours after replacing the disk, all 12 disks are flashing rapidly (yellow) on the lower light indicator. Does this mean it's still rebuilding, or is something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't seen that, when our MSA60 rebuilds I think that only the new disk is flashing, but I might be wrong. 
I suggest you start by checking status on the [HP Array Configuration Utility](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html), and if that doesn't make sense call HP for assistance.

Comment: HP ACU reports that parity initialization is queued or in progress. I got a hold of a more experienced tech here, and he says it can take days to rebuild an array of that size. Thanks for your time, 3molo. :)

Comment: No worries! Raid 6 takes longer to rebuild, but seem to have less performance impact on the array.